# VueJs imports my state twice when published to npm

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-component, vuejs3, state-management

I plan to modularize my vue3 App by splitting up parts into their own npm package. However, when publishe the package to npm, the "consumer" app imports some files multipe times. E.g. when I import a store file from my package, it loads it multiple times and, hence, I cannot share the state between my components.

I created a small example:

*myComponent.vue* - It imports the store and the component can later be used in the main "consumer" app.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { store } from "./store";
</script>

<template>
  <div class="box">
    <b>This is the State Value:</b><br />
    {{ store.mylibval }}
  </div>
</template>
```

*store.ts* - This is a simple file to keep the state

```
import { reactive } from "vue";

console.log ("store imported")

export const store = reactive({
  mylibval: "Hello World",
});
```

*myService.ts* - this is a service function that can be used by the "consumer" app to modify the state.

```
import { store } from "./store";

export function useMyLibFunc() {
  const setVal = (val: string) => {
    store.mylibval = val;
  };

  const getVal = () => {
    return store.mylibval;
  };

  return {
    setVal,
    getVal,
  };
}
```

And finally my *App.vue*. For testing purpose, I used the same App.vue in my "library" app and the "consumer" app - I just adjusted the import paths

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import MyComponentVue from "mylibrary/src/main/MyComponent.vue"
import { useMyLibFunc } from "mylibrary/src/main/myService";

const myLibService = useMyLibFunc();

const setNewVal = () => {
  myLibService.setVal("Hello Moon");
};
</script>

<template>
  <MyComponentVue />
  <button @click="setNewVal">Set new Val</button>
</template>
```

When I now run the app in the "library" environment, everything works fine. However, when I publish the files to npm and install them in consumer app, the state is not working. I also can see in the consumer app the console output "store imported" twice.

I guess the component imports the store and my service imports the store again, hence they do not share the state. Why is that, and how can I fix that?

Comment: Because ./store module is different for these packages. If you need it to be a singleton, it should exist in a single package. Either its own or in "service" package. Btw it may make no sense to treat a store and a service as separate entities. You may notice that exisiting global stores (Vuex, Pinia, etc) do both

Comment: Do I really need to create a new package only to persist a single variable? I also tried to use provide/inject, however, when I use InjectionKey, the Symbol is also different, and hence it does not work. My plugin should contain a component that displays the output of a variable; and the main app should access an API / methods to set the content...

Comment: I'm not sure what was the reasoning for creating multiple packages here. But you need to keep a store in a separate package that will be used by other dependents. It's up to you if a store and a service should be separated or can be a single thing. It's unnecessary to make injection key a symbol, it could be a string. There's also Symbol.for for this.